# Fixing crashed VirtualBox installation

Tags: apt, virtualbox

I've recently installed VirtualBox via `apt-get`:

```
apt-get install virtualbox
```

It worked totally fine. During work in my virtual system I experienced a crash. Since then I'm not able of starting VirtualBox anymore. A window pops up showing me the following error:

```
Callee RC: NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED (0x80040154)
```

I removed virtual box using

```
apt-get remove
```

as well as

```
apt-get purge
```

. I installed VirtualBox using `dpkg` and the package provided from [Oracle](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). Same story. Once again I purged it and tried the installation provided by Ubuntu Softwarecenter. Didn't work, too.

I run a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. What else could I try to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions of your /tmp directory are actually

`drwxrwsrwx`
which is wrong.

The correct permissions for /tmp are 1777 where the first digit is the 't' (temp) bit. Change the permissions of your /tmp directory to these permissions

Or try on the terminal:

`sudo chmod -s /tmp`

And then run Virtualbox again

Source: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/3568

Comment: After posting the question I stumbled about this solution, too. Didn't work. After seeing your answer I again gave it I try. Finally it worked but I had to totally recreate the `/tmp` directory.